# Slide Menu in ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, ios8

I want a slide menu like Facebook right barbutton animation view in the viewController. My app delegate is already setting routeviewcontroller.

But I want to change my current view controller as slideOut menu.

This is my example but it is in right side:

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [InteractiveSideMenu](https://github.com/handsomecode/InteractiveSideMenu) library for your purpose. Just set `visibleContentWidth` to 0 for `TransitionOptionsBuilder`.
Here is an example:

```
override func menuTransitionOptionsBuilder() -> TransitionOptionsBuilder? {
    return TransitionOptionsBuilder() { builder in
        builder.visibleContentWidth = 0
}
```

You can find more details [here](https://github.com/handsomecode/InteractiveSideMenu/blob/master/Sample/Sample/HostViewController.swift).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a view and give its x coordinate in "minus", i.e keep it out of screen. For instance your view's width is 100 pixels, so make it's x:-100. This way, it won't be visible on screen at first. In this view make a tableview with all the fields(News, Comments, Maps etc). Now, when the "menu" button will be pressed, call uiview's animateWithDuration function and move x to "0". And when the button is pressed again, move x back to -100.